# .ToString returns System.Object[] in Error

Tags: powershell-2.0

With PowerShell 2.0 if I run the following on a Windows 7 machine:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress }
```

it returns

```
192.168.83.26
fe80::<IPv6 address>
```

If I run:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress }.ToString()
```

It returns

```
System.Object[]
```

Why? And how can I resolve it?

FYI, I'm actually trying to use `.ToString().split('.')[0..2] -join '.'` but I'm pretty sure it's the `.ToString` that's causing the issue

---

```
function Get-IPAddress{
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress } |
Select -Expand IPAddress).split('.')[0..2] -join '.'
}
Get-IPAddress
```

returns `192.168.10` on PoSh 3.  This doesn't seem to work on PoSh 2, and returns the `System.Object[]' that I stated above. The error complains about not having a Method named trim.  Others have suggested declaring it as a String, but I've been unable to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
? { $_.IPAddress } ).ipaddress | % { ($_ -split '\.')[0..2]}
```

This:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? { $_.IPAddress } ).ipaddress
```

returns always an `array of strings` also in the case of a *single ip address*.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesnt work is IPAddress property is part of a PropertySet, the console output makes it look like a string but it is not

Not entirely sure what you require for your end result but you can try

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | %{ $_.IPAddress }) -join " "
```

Comment: see my edit below the line above. I can't work out how to format stuff as code in this comment box

Comment: what is the desired result that your want - just the IP address on its own ?

Comment: The first three octets eg 192.168.10

Answer (score 0):

As Christian mentioned, the $_.IPAddress property is an array of strings.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | % { 
    if($_.IPAddress){
        $_.IPAddress[0]
    }
}
```

Using your string manipulation:

```
$ip = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | % { if($_.IPAddress){$_.IPAddress[0] }}
$ip.ToString().split('.')[0..2] -join '.'

10.15.0
```

As a one-liner:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | % { if($_.IPAddress){$_.IPAddress[0] }}).ToString().split('.')[0..2] -join '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

`toString` is causing the problem.

you need to pipe "out-string"

the `tostring()` gives you the class type to string as defined